# C#.net - How can I show a dynamically generated textarea on button click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to show a text area based on a button click. Pretty simple, but the textarea and button are dynamically generated using Knockout js. My current code works, except it only expands the first text area. There are several projects displayed.

HTML (the button and textarea are the last two controls):

```
 <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
    <div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  
        <input type="button" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" onclick="displayTextArea()" value="Yes" />
        <textarea id="oppyDoneTextArea" placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." style=" display:none; height:75px; " /><br />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayTextArea() {
    var my_disply = document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display;
    if (my_disply == "block")
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "block";
}
```

As you can see, the controls are dynamically generated based on the objects that Knockout binds. So, using ID's is a bad idea because it would generate duplicate IDs. That is currently my problem now -- this code works for the first text area but doesn't work for the rest of the projects that display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your button is of `type=submit`and is causing a postback, change:

```
<input type="submit" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" onclick="displayTextArea()" value="Yes" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" onclick="displayTextArea()" value="Yes" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the page refresh issue. Now, my next issue is that it's not working for any other text areas -- I'm assuming because of the duplicate IDs. The "ko foreach: project" dynamically generates this div for each project.

Comment: That really is another question for StackOverflow, ask a new question I can answer how you can handle that with Knockout, please post a url to the new question in the comments here and also mark my answer to this question as correct for Stack Overflow tidy

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964957/c-net-how-can-i-show-a-dynamically-generated-textarea-on-button-click-using-k