# How can I show a dynamically generated textarea on button click using Knockout js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, textarea

I want to show a text area based on a button click. Pretty simple, but the textarea and button are dynamically generated using Knockout js. My current code works, except it only expands the first text area. There are several projects displayed.

HTML (the button and textarea are the last two controls):

```
 <!-- ko foreach: projects -->
    <div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  
        <input type="button" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" data-bind="click: toggleTextArea" value="Yes" />
        <textarea id="oppyDoneTextArea" placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." data-bind="visible: show" /><br />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayTextArea() {
    var my_disply = document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display;
    if (my_disply == "block")
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "block";
}
```

Knockout View Model:

```
    function ProjectViewModel(proj) {
        //console.log(proj);
        var self = this;
        self.projects = ko.observableArray(proj);
var project = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.show = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleTextArea= function(){
        self.show(!self.show());
        };
      }; 
    };
```

As you can see, the controls are dynamically generated based on the objects that Knockout binds. So, using ID's is a bad idea because it would generate duplicate IDs. That is currently my problem now -- this code works for the first text area but doesn't work for the rest of the projects that display.

Comment: Why don't you use the `visible` and `click` bindings provided by knockout? In the `click` handler just toogle an observable which show/hides your textarea through the `visible` binding...

Comment: @nemesv I tried that, but then it leaves a blank space where the textarea would be. I had a function displayTextArea() that would be called by the button click event using visibility, but the display:none seems like it doesn't reserve the space where the textarea should be.

Comment: Can you create js-fiddle to show your problem?

Comment: @MaxBrodin It doesn't quite work in the fiddle but you can see that there are several projects. When I click the button "Yes", a textarea should slide down under the corresponding project and push any content below it down. Currently, in my working application, the button click event only pushes the first textarea of the first project down (probably due to the duplicate IDs) http://jsfiddle.net/skylit/g1wbbLrc

Comment: However I am not sure how to not have duplicate IDs because the textarea is dynamically generated OR how to not use the ID. In the future, this textarea will be bound by knockout once I have a database schema set up for it. User's past submissions will be displayed in the textarea.

Comment: @nemesv referring to my reply to you, I would really like to use the toggle() because the slideDown feature would be ideal -- having the textarea slide down rather than just appearing. But using visibility property leaves a blank space of where the textarea would be -- leaving a gap in the page.

Comment: @SKY take a look at the animated transitions example I think it's what are you looking for http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

Answer (score 1):

I would try creating 2 properties on the project model, 'show' and 'toggleTextArea':

```
<!-- ko foreach: projects -->
<div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
            <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  
    <input type="button" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" value="Yes" data-bind="click: toggleTextArea" />
    <textarea id="oppyDoneTextArea" placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." style="height:75px;" data-bind="visible: show" /><br />
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

your project model could be something like this:

```
var project = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.show = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleTextArea= function(){
        self.show(!self.show());
    };
};
```

This allows the click of the button to toggle the status of the textarea.

Comment: I added my view model to my post. I'm new to knockout. I have self.projects defined, would I add your code to my currently defined projects? Or just simply add it?

Comment: I tried just adding your code to my view model but it didn't work.

Comment: You pass an array into your ProjectViewModel, with the name of proj.

I assume this is an array of knockoutmodels.
It is the same model that has the property: projectDescription.
That is where the show and toggleTextArea function should be.

Comment: Right. "Proj" is what's returned from the server to the client in json. I updated my code to include what you suggested.  It still doesn't quite work - the projects are not displaying properly as well as the text area.

Comment: Can you show me the model definition for the Proj model, the one that has projectDescription in it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you ca try this to get the result.

HTML (the button and textarea are the last two controls):

```
<!-- ko foreach: projects -->
    <div id="eachOppyProject" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/tools/oppy/' + guid }" style="font-size: 25px;"><span class="link" data-bind="    value: guid, text: name"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: projectDescription"></tr>
                <tr data-bind="text: guid"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <span class="forminputtitle">Have you done project this before?</span>  
        <input type="button" id="oppyBtn" class="btnOppy" onclick="displayTextArea(this)" value="Yes" />
        <textarea id="oppyDoneTextArea" placeholder="Tell us a little of what you've done." style=" display:none; height:75px; " /><br />
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

JavaScript:

```
function displayTextArea(element) {
    var my_disply = element.nextSibling
    if (my_disply == "block")
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "none";
    else
        document.getElementById('oppyDoneTextArea').style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope it will help you and will work only when the textarea is the next sibling to button on clicking of which you have to show the textarea